IntelliJ Stuck On "Saving '[project name]' settings" when exiting
Lately when I exit IntelliJ (in Ubuntu, Java 21 installed), a dialog box pops up stating "Saving '[project name]' settings" and it never goes away. This used to not happen.
Anyone know how I can figure out what's going on? I am a bit nervous ever time I end the task that things are going to get corrupted.
Thanks!
I just click the 'X' to exit.
Expected settings to save very quickly and the application to exit.

If you are on Linux, please see if this workaround helps. If it's not the case or the issue persists, please contact support with the logs and the thread dumps.

Started to happen recently on my Windows work computer and macOS at home for different projects, a coincidence?

Workaround:

Click IDE main menu Help | Edit Custom Properties,
add ide.ui.new.file.chooser=true in a new line.
Use File | Invalidate Caches
enable the "Clear file system cache and Local History" option
Invalidate and Restart to clear the file access cache.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-74471/UI-freeze-on-IDE-start-in-2023.2-PerModulePackageCacheService

Except the answer above(which didn't help in my case), I've deleted .idea folder in the project.
My environment:
MacOS
Editor: IntelliJ.
Hope this helps.
